# How to stop running node in docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I have just installed dockers and installed node.
I am able to run a basic express site. My issue now is I can't stop it. Control-C is not doing anything.

Temporarily what I did to exit was:

1. Close the docker's terminal.
2. Open a new one.
3. Search for all docker containers that is running.
4. Then `docker stop [container]`

Is this the proper way?

Comment: What command are you using to run the container?

Comment: To stop the process you don't have to stop the container, however normally that's exactly what you would do. You probably run just a web server in the docker, so stopping the node essentially is same as stopping the container

Answer (score 29):

As described here: [github: docker-node best practice](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md)

You can add the `--init` flag to your docker run command.

```
docker run -it --init -p 3000:3000 --name nodetest mynodeimage
```

Comment: in my case `-it` is enough. I'm using nodejs clustering (master + worker processes) within a docker container. And nodejs is run via `npm run script-name`

Answer (score 28):

I don't know if this is too late. But the correct way to do this is to catch the SIGINT (interrupt signal in your javascript).

```
var process = require('process')
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.info("Interrupted")
  process.exit(0)
})
```

This should do the trick when you press Ctrl+C

Comment: I've found that also adding the same sort of handler for `SIGTERM` helps Docker "gracefully exit" a node container more quickly than waiting for the timeout.

Comment: You should never need to call `process.exit()` - node will exit on it's own once your program stops "doing things". This means clearing any intervals/timers, closing any db connections, closing your http server, etc. If node doesn't exit on it's own, it's generally an indication that you haven't "cleaned up" everything.

Answer (score 16):

I came across this same problem today, and struggled to find an explanation/solution. I discovered (through trial and error) that this only occurs when the CMD in the Dockerfile is set to:

```
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

However, Ctrl+C works fine when the CMD is changed to:

```
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The `npm start` script in my `package.json` file is set to `node server.js`, so I have no idea why this change works, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: This method solved for me, but only when I added command line arguments `-t` and `-i` to the `docker run` command. Example: `docker run -p 4444:4444 -t -i my/image`

Comment: The `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` works because `npm` scripts are run with `/bin/sh` which handles the signal.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but using the `process.on('SIGNIT')` solution did.

Answer (score 3):

A [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) should have gave you back the prompt, avoiding the need for CTRL+C, or closing the docker terminal.

Once you log back in that terminal, a [`docker ps -a`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) + [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) should be enough to make your container exit (you still need to remove it before trying to launch it again)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to stop node without stopping the container, you could go inside the container and run:

```
$ ps aux | grep node #to obtain process ID (value in second column)
$ kill <process ID>
```

Answer (score 3):

As a part of solution, you can open your package.js and add 3 new commands/scripts :

```
"scripts": {    

"docker-build-and-run": "docker build -t image-dev-local . && docker run -p 3001:3001 --name container-dev-local image-dev-local",
"docker-stop-and-clear": "(docker stop container-dev-local || true) && (docker rm container-dev-local || true)",
"docker-run": "npm run docker-stop-and-clear && npm run docker-build-and-run"

}
```

and just simply run in the terminal :

```
npm run docker-run
```

to up your app on 3001 port in docker and have fun. Every next run will clear previous and build/run again.

To stop and delete it, just run :

```
npm run docker-stop-and-clear
```

Comment: Zhyve Belarus! :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. docker stop `<containerName/containerId>`
2. docker kill --signal=SIGINT `<containerName/containerId>`
3. docker rm -f `<containerName/containerId>`

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather you need both **-t** and **-i** for Ctrl-C to work as expected. Command like this would be helpful i believe.

Simple example which i can think of this below
Case 1 to retain container:

```
$ ID=$(sudo docker run -t -d ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b)
$ sudo docker attach $ID
Control-C
$ sudo docker ps
```

Case 2 to terminate the container:

```
$ ID=$(sudo docker run -t -i -d ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b)
$ sudo docker attach $ID
Control-C
$ sudo docker ps
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use in the `Dockerfile` this command for starting the application

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "node app.js"]
```

then we can listen in the `app.js` with

```
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('SIGTERM received, shutting down...');
});
```

and we have to run the dockerfile with the `--init` flag

```
docker run --init -p 3000:3000 --name nodetest mynodeimage
```

or we can add in `docker-compose` beginning from version `3.7` the entry

```
init: true
```

to the desired service.
For the app to receive the signal you should use `docker stop nodetest` or `docker-compose down`. Shutting down with `Ctrl+C` does not send the `SIGTERM` signal.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the node console, after running `docker run -it node`,
you can exit with the following:

- Enter `.exit`
- Press two times

  - ctrl+c
  - ctrl+d

---

If the node container is started in detached mode `docker run -d node`,
you can stop it with `docker stop <CONTAINER_ID or CONTAINER_NAME>`.

For example, assuming you want to kill the newest node container:

```
docker stop $(docker ps | grep node | awk 'NR == 1 { print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type this in your terminal:

```
process.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

first, search current running container and container id

```
$ docker ps -a
```

second, container stop or kill with container id

```
$ docker stop <container-id>
```

or

```
$ docker kill <container-id>
```