# how to quit in teminal when running docket in terminal mode

Tags: docker

I am running

```
docker run --rm -t -p 3000:3000 --name node-app foo/node
```

How do i quit ctrl + C does not seem to work.
Currently I have to open another terminal to stop the docker. Is this the only option?

Comment: Checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36637912/how-to-stop-running-node-in-docker

Answer (score 1):

If you use -t and -i then Control-C will terminate the container. When using -i with -t then you have to use Control-P Control-Q to detach without terminating

Test 1:

```
$ ID=$(sudo docker run -t -d ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b)
$ sudo docker attach $ID
Control-C
$ sudo docker ps
```

The container is still listed.

Test 2:

```
$ ID=$(sudo docker run -t -i -d ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b)
$ sudo docker attach $ID
Control-C
$ sudo docker ps
```

The container is terminated